# Attacking weak PRNG Math.round(Math.random() * 30D)

Tags: java, random

Is it possible for an attacker to predict, following a random generator of the form `Math.round(Math.random() * 30D)`, with a sufficient number of values? I know that the `Math.random` is a weak PRNG, but does rounding up the value not prevent brute force attack or analysis (as there are many on this PRNG)? And if that does not stop, how could the attacker proceed?

Comment: Gut feeling: if things were that easy, cryptography wouldn't be that hard, would it.

Comment: This question is mostly off-topic, but why would you expect your countermeasure to work? You would need to understand methods of attacking the RNG already, and your countermeasure would be geared toward defeating them. It doesn't sound like that is the case.